# what is the equivalent reference for "this" in C/C

Tags: c#

Guys i just started to learn C# and i have no idea about "this" reference in c# someone can give me a very simple example in real life. I mean why do i need to use "this" in C# or where can i use "this" what is the benefit?

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously? [this C# Reference - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx). Google and ANY OOP tutorial will give you **this** (pun intended) answer in ~5 seconds.

Comment: I saw that but i dont really get the point of using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The this keyword eliminates the need to have unique variable names for constructors.

Oftentimes, you already named a variable well and to have a unique name for the constructor, you would either have to come up with a new name or otherwise mar the good one you have.

In addition, it allows you to name local variables and instance variables the same and have a way to use the one you wish.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    //instance variable
    private String myVar;

    public Foo(String myVar)
    {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }

    public void someFunc()
    {
        String myVar = "Hello";// local variable
        this.myVar = "World";//instance variable
        Console.WriteLine(myVar + this.myVar);//prints HelloWorld
    }
}
```

In C++ 'this' is a pointer, so you would need to reference members using the '->' operator.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty good example is when you have a class with fields and a constructor with arguments of the same name. Using "this", you can assign the field with the argument name. There are other ambiguities that this can solve along this same line.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int foobar;
    public MyClass(int foobar)
    {
        this.foobar = foobar;
    }
}
```